Is there any way to use Hibernate Envers with custom queries
i wanted to ask if there is a way to use custom queries for lookup of revisioned entities.
The reason is that i want to be in full control of when my entities are loaded and sometimes i also have some more complex joins which are not that easy to reflect
Following are my (sample) entities:
@Data
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name = "Product")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private Long orderId;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Order order;
}

@Data
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name = "Order")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String text;
    private BigDecimal amount;

}

I would like to do something like this
    public void findProductByOrderIdAndRevision(Long orderId, Long revisionFromOrder) {
AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);

return auditReader.createQuery().forEntitiesAtRevision(Product.class, revisionFromOrder)
        .traverseRelation("order", JoinType.INNER, "products", AuditEntity.id().eq(orderId))
        .getResultList();
    }

but this also returns old values which were not in the relation at the time of this revision
Is there any possible way to achieve this?
Best regards

(I don't really see why your query would return wrong results, maybe you can look at the actual SQL which can be logged using org.hibernate.sql: INFO)
Otherwise you can actually write HQL queries using the envers entities (envers also does that internally)
The naming convention would be like "com.example.Product_AUD" and the relation tables will be named just like the database tables.
For more information about the underlying model you can look at EnversService#getEntitiesConfigurations.
At least that's what I am doing for more complex queries.
